# Images not getting retrieved in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to show images on template using img, but the images are not getting retrieved.

Template

```
{% for a in db_fetch %} 
        <img class="metro" src="site_media/{{ a.image.url }}"><b></b><br>
{% endfor %}
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PWD, "../downloads/")
MEDIA_URL = '/downloads/'
```

images are stored at location /django-project/downloads/images/*.jpg

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try these sentences in the settings.py put the following code:

> ```
> URL_PROJECT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
> NAME_PROJECT = os.path.basename(URL_PROJECT)
> ```

After:

> ```
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(URL_PROJECT,'downloads')
> MEDIA_URL = '/downloads/'
> ```

And the templates use:

```
 <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{a.image.url}}">
```

Comment: `{% load staticfiles %}` then `{% static a.image.url %}`

Comment: Check in the inspect element the browser the url the image and put it to here to check the error